# Dock won't appear on other displays

Tags: macos, display, dock

I know, you can't have the dock on both screens at the same time, and I know that there's a 'swipe down' gesture I'm supposed to be able to do with the mouse to make the dock appear. I just can't seem to get that to work, though... I've done this before on other computers.

Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11) clean install done yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also fix the dock on a other screen:

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Click on Displays
3. Click on Arrangement
4. Swipe the white bar from one screen to the other

If this won't work, also check the alt + cmd + d keycombination to show / hide the dock.